# gifs in html5 app make the app slowers?

Tags: android, ios, html, jquery-mobile, mosync

I am working on an html5 mobile app for a website. The website contains a lot of gifs(about 5-10 per page) on its pages which are making the app events, scroll, drag, css animations, and everything very slow. if i get rid of the gifs the app runs fine. I have tested the app on both android(nexus 7) and ios(iphone 5 and ipad 4).

I was thinking of showing a still image and then play it on some event, but it was spoiling the webpage's idea.I am using the mosync sdk for development.

Any suggestions on what can i do to not make it slower?

Answer (score 0):

Without some code its difficult to assess what needs to be done, but depending of your knowledge in Obj-c - you will need to asynchronously load the gifs, SDWebImage at github has such a feature.

Comment: what about android and other platforms? How do websites like tumblr do it?